# Attach file to Outlook with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Currently I'm writing a GUI Powershell script to run PSR.exe so that the helpdesk can capture the user problems then email the output to the help desk with minimal input.

The problem I'm having is attaching a file that was generated using environment variables. It works if I use static file name as shown in the example, however no computer name has the same hostname and user at the same time. How do I tell to attach the file from the two variables used to create the file?

```
#Directory storage
$DIR = "D:\Reports"

#Max number of recent screen captures
$MAX = "100"

#Captures Screen Shots from the recording
$SC = "1"

#Turn GUI mode on or off
$STR = "0"

#Caputres the current computer name
$PCName = "$ENV:COMPUTERNAME"

#Use either the local name or domain name
#$User = "$ENV:UserDomainName"
$User = "$ENV:UserName"

#Work in progress.
$File = "D:\Reports\LabComputer-Tester01.zip"

$buttonStart_Click={
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path D:\Reports
    psr.exe /start /output $DIR\$PCName-$User.zip /maxsc $MAX /sc $SC /gui $STR
}

$buttonStop_Click={
        psr.exe /stop
}

$buttonEmail_Click={
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $Mail.To = "deaconf19@gmail.com"
    $Mail.Subject = "Capture Report"
    $Mail.Body = "Something in here"
    $Mail.Attachments.Add($File)
    $Mail.Send()
}
```

I changed `$File = "D:\Reports\LabComputer-Tester01.zip"` to `$File '\$DIR\\$PCName-$User.zip'` I added the single tick and another backslash to the variable

Comment: I must be missing something. Why don't you set $file=$DIR\$PCName-$User.zip

Comment: I tried that and get this error ERROR: Unexpected token '\$PCName-$User.zip' in expression or statement.

Comment: I solved my problem I was not escaping the backslash properly

Comment: @JeremyA1 that 'NamesOfStuff' sort of gives it away... I assume just changing to "" fixed it?

Comment: @JeremyA1, post your solution as answer so this question can successfully closed.

Comment: Why are you using Outlook to send the email? If PowerShell is capturing all of the data & attaching the file, you can send an email via `send-mailmessage` and eliminate a whole class of complications.

Comment: PowerShell is not capturing all the data. A program executes to capture the data then zips the file up. That file needs to be attached and the Body of the email contains variables that I was unable to display in the send-mailmessage

Answer (score 0):

I changed `$File = "D:\Reports\LabComputer-Tester01.zip"` to `$File '\$DIR\\$PCName-$User.zip'` I added the single tick and another backslash to the variable